# How to find census block groups closest to coordinates? (using python, not ArcGIS)

Tags: python, gis, census

I'm decent with python but new to geospatial coding.

I have a list of coordinates. I also the shapefiles for census block groups.

I'd like to know how to find the census block groups within 1 mile of each coordinate. Even if only a small portion of the block group is within 1 mile, I still would like that group to show up in the results. I would also like the sets of nearby block groups to be associated with the coordinates they are near.

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I will try to explain more clearly.

Thanks!

P.S. I think that this question is getting at some of the things I'm struggling with (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/polygon-overlay-with-shapely). The implication is that I should use Shapely, create a buffer for each set of coordinates I have, and then somehow find which census areas get caught in a union.

Comment: So what was the result of using Shapely, where are you stuck. You will get much better responses if you show what you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any code... I've been reading up on geospatial python all day but I don't really know where to start

Comment: You might want to give gis.stackexchange a look, they are GIS and python friendly, as well as open source solutions